# Работа с потоками WinAPI

Tags: c, многопоточность, winapi

У меня на форме расположены 3 кнопки (Start/Resume,Clear,Exit). При нажатии на Start создается N потоков, и в цикле они продолжают выполняться(пересоздаются),пока не будут выполнены условия. В это время работа с формой останавливается,т.е. она принимает сообщения о нажатии кнопок,но не обрабатывает их ,пока не закончат работу новые потоки.

Вопрос: Можно ли как-либо дать пользователю возможность нажимать кнопки на форме с последующей их обработкой? `Sleep()`,`SuspendThread()`,`WaitForMultipleObjects(...,INFINITE)` не работают из-за цикла.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFuncCycle(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    HWND hDlg = (HWND)lpParam;

    SetWindowText(btnStart_Pause, "Resume");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        GetObject(cars[i].hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
        /* создать совместимый с контекстом окна контекст в памяти */
        hCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        /* делаем загруженный битмап текущим в совместимом контексте */
        hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, cars[i].hBitmap);
        UpdateWindow(hDlg);
        StretchBlt(hdc, cars[i].x, cars[i].y, Bitmap.bmWidth / 2,
            Bitmap.bmHeight / 2, hCompatibleDC, 0, 0, Bitmap.bmWidth,
            Bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

        /* вновь делаем старый битмап текущим */
        SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, hOldBitmap);
        /* удалить загруженный битмап */
        //DeleteObject(cars[i].hBitmap);
        /* удалить совместимый контекст */
        DeleteDC(hCompatibleDC);
    }
    Sleep(500);
    DWORD index;
    BOOL in = false;
    DWORD buf[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    BOOL finish[5] = { false, false, false, false, false };
    BOOL pause[5] = { false, false, false, false, false };
    do{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            buf[i] = cars[i].x;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (!finish[i]){
                hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, &cars[i],
                    CREATE_SUSPENDED, &dwThreadID[i]);
                SetThreadPriority(hThreads[i], THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (!finish[i]){
                ResumeThread(hThreads[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            /* получть размерность изображения */
            if (!finish[i]){
                GetObject(cars[i].hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
                /* создать совместимый с контекстом окна контекст в памяти */
                hCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                /* делаем загруженный битмап текущим в совместимом контексте */
                hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, cars[i].hBitmap);
                RECT rect;
                rect.bottom = cars[i].y + Bitmap.bmHeight / 2;
                rect.left = buf[i] - Bitmap.bmWidth;
                rect.right = cars[i].x + Bitmap.bmWidth;
                rect.top = cars[i].y;
                InvalidateRect(hDlg, &rect, TRUE);
                UpdateWindow(hDlg);
                StretchBlt(hdc, cars[i].x, cars[i].y, Bitmap.bmWidth / 2,
                    Bitmap.bmHeight / 2, hCompatibleDC, 0, 0, Bitmap.bmWidth,
                    Bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

                /* вновь делаем старый битмап текущим */
                SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, hOldBitmap);
                /* удалить загруженный битмап */
                //DeleteObject(cars[i].hBitmap);
                /* удалить совместимый контекст */
                DeleteDC(hCompatibleDC);
                /* освободить основной контекст, завершая перерисовку рабочей области окна */
                Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        bool check = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            //sprintf(str, "i = %d,Lenght = %d",i, coordinate[i]);
            //MessageBox(NULL, str, "Info", MB_OK);
            if (cars[i].x >= rcClient.right - 300 && !finish[i]){
                finish[i] = true;
                BITMAP bufBitmap;
                GetObject(cars[i].hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bufBitmap);
                GetObject(Numbers[whoFirst], sizeof(BITMAP), &Bitmap);
                /* создать совместимый с контекстом окна контекст в памяти */
                hCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
                /* делаем загруженный битмап текущим в совместимом контексте */
                hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, Numbers[whoFirst]);
                UpdateWindow(hDlg);
                StretchBlt(hdc, cars[i].x + bufBitmap.bmWidth / 2, cars[i].y, Bitmap.bmWidth / 12,
                    Bitmap.bmHeight / 12, hCompatibleDC, 0, 0, Bitmap.bmWidth,
                    Bitmap.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

                /* вновь делаем старый битмап текущим */
                SelectObject(hCompatibleDC, hOldBitmap);
                /* удалить загруженный битмап */
                //DeleteObject(cars[i].hBitmap);
                /* удалить совместимый контекст */
                DeleteDC(hCompatibleDC);
                whoFirst += 1;
            }
            if (!finish[i])
                check = false;
        }
        if (check){
            in = true;
        }
        WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
    } while (!in);

    //WaitForMultipleObjects(5, hThreads, TRUE, 3000);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
        finish[i] = false;
        whoFirst = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно цикл тоже вынести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Цикл,т.е. данные в нем? Или вместе со счетчиком?

Comment: А если у меня в этом цикле идет работа с графической составляющей формы? Что делать

Comment: @НикитаАлексеев синхронизирвать. Например посылкой сообщений. Ну а если для отображения графики используются данные цикла или потоков, то блокировать их в основном потоке на время использования.

Comment: Посылать сообщения из других потоков в гуевый: [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)/[PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx). Также смотрите [APC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951(v=vs.85).aspx). А вообще, покажите кусочек своего кода, это многое прояснит.